# Error in GTM: Computed property.ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: computed property

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have the following function I want to run within Google Tag Manager but I am getting the following error:

> This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: computed property.

Below is the function I am trying to run. How would I alter this to work with GTM?
Thanks

```
var compactObject = function(data) {
  if (typeof data !== 'object') {
    return data;
  }

  return Object.keys(data).reduce(function(accumulator, key) {
    var isObject = typeof data[key] === 'object';
    var value = isObject ? compactObject(data[key]) : data[key];
    var isEmptyObject = isObject && !Object.keys(value).length;
    if (value === undefined || isEmptyObject) {
      return accumulator;
    }

    return Object.assign(accumulator, {[key]: value});
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015

Comment: `{[key]: value}` is  a computed property. Re-write that section so that it doesn't use this.

Comment: any ideas how I would re-write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You main question appears to be:

> How can I re-write `{[key]: value}` so that it is supported in older
> versions of JS

You can re-write the computed property syntax using the longer (legacy) version

```js
var obj = {};
obj[key] = value;

return Object.assign(accumulator, obj);
```